# JPanel slide on the fly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, slider, jpanel

I have some JPanels on a JFrame and want to move them while the program runs.
My code is many lines so I cannot paste the whole of it here but here is a sample of the function `toggle` where the moving takes place.

```
for(int h=frame.height; h<HEIGHT; h++){
    toolbar.setBounds(0, h, size.width, size.height);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(counter);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Scene.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Essentially, I want the JPanel to move from north to south.

When I call this `toggle` function during the initialization off the program
then when I start it, I can see the JPanel moving correctly. If I add a keylistener so I can trigger the JPanel to move when the program is running, the following happens: The program does nothing for the time that the JPanel needs to move, and after this time I see the JPanel on its final position. Should I somehow repaint the jframe of the jpanel during the previous sample or what?

Comment: I don't think that your posted code and text is adequate to allow us to be able to understand your problem enough to answer it. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyListener is called on the awt thread. If you try to animate from the awt thread nothing will happen, since swing paints on the awt thread. You need to create a new thread for animation and use Swing.InvokeLater or similiar to paint your animation.

Comment: Or use a Swing Timer. 1+